# Sending IP address through socket in C

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock

I currently have a working client (written in C++) and a working server (written in C). I'm currently trying to figure out how to send to the client from the server a message that says "Hello, (Clients IP address)", also I'd like to respond to the client when he says "Hello" with a message of my choosing. Also when the client sends "quit" I'd like to disconnect the client, but not shutdown the server. Below is my code.

```
 while(true)     // loop forever
 {
  client = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);      // accept connections

  unsigned long ulAddr = from.sin_addr.s_addr;

  char *client_ip;
  client_ip = inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr);

  cout << "Welcome, " << client_ip << endl; // usually prints hello %s
  // cout << "client before thread:" << (int) client << endl;
  // create our recv_cmds thread and pass client socket as a parameter
  CreateThread(NULL, 0,receive_cmds,(LPVOID)client, 0, &thread);
 }

 WSACleanup();
```

updated code* my current problem is that it just prints `Welcome %s`, not an actual IPv4 address.

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: `char welcome[90] = "Welcome %s",inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr); `   does not work, I'm not sure how else to send the client's ip address.

Comment: You might want to read the `strcat` and/or `sprintf()` man page (if using C), and/or the `ostringstream` man page (if using C++)... they'll show you how to populate welcome (or an `ostringstream` instead).

Comment: Why do you want to send the address to the server - server should get this information from system when receiving connection - it will even be more robust - what if client is behind a NAT?

Comment: For this particular project we would be on the same network, it's just some friends and I messing around with making our own chat program.

Answer (score 3):

> char welcome[90] = "Welcome %s",inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr);

You can't format a string buffer in a declaration like that.  You need to use `sprintf()` or similar function instead, eg:

```
char welcome[90];
sprintf(welcome, "Welcome %s", inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));
```

Or else use a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string welcome = "Welcome " + std::string(inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));
...
write(nsockfd , welcome.c_str() , welcome.length());
```